# Export java file as external jar in android

Tags: java, android, jar

how can i export one of my classes (non activity) and use it as external jar in my application. I need to do this because of reasons.

I have tried to remove my package name from top of my class. Then via eclipse export as jar file and added to my projects. I got no errors in the code but when I ran the application it crashed with:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(12762): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(12762): java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
E/AndroidRuntime(12762): The declared package "" does not match the expected package "com.myapp"
```

The thing is I wish that this jar can be used in any other application and package

Comment: **"I have tried to remove my package name from top of my class."** - Why are you trying to do this? If it's because you don't want it to have the same package name as your original app then simply create a new package called, for example, com.mycompany.libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some solutions:
1) You can write a little project with this class, and make it library (project Properties -> Andoid -> enable Is Library -> OK). Then you can include this lib-project in another project (project Properties -> Andoid -> Add -> pick this lib-projectt -> OK.)
2) You can create class with same name, and then copy past all code into.
3) You can create jar file with this class, and then include it as library. Use [this tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/create-jar-file-in-java-eclipse/) to create jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse automatically generates .jar files of your *library* projects in the `/bin` folder. You can copy this file and use it in other projects.

Comment: Eclipse generates jar files of each class of my package?